# Should I use "me and her" or "her and me" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence, phrase-usage

- I was surprised Paola agreed to come on the trip, just her and me.
- I was surprised Paola agreed to come on the trip, just me and her.

Both versions sound OK to me. Or is it there a more appropriate one?

Comment: Don't rely on your intuitions about English grammaticality, then. _Accept_ can't take an infinitive complement, so they're both ungrammatical. The order of _me_ and _her_ is not a grammatical issue, any more than the order of _Bill_ and _Paola_ would be in the same context. Get the real stuff right before you worry about imaginary problem.

Comment: @John Lawler Sorry, could you give me a correct example of the sentence then?

Comment: _I was surprised Paola had agreed to come on the trip._ Change _accepted_ to _agreed_, which can take an infinitive complement; and note that the idiom is _go **on** a trip_, not _go to_. Like I said, get the real stuff right first.

Comment: *I was surprised Paola had agreed to come on the trip with me.* or *I was surprised Paola had agreed to come with me on my trip.*

Comment: Polite phrasing (not grammar) tends to suggest you/me is the last entry in a list. *Those on the trip were Bob, Suzy, Jane, and me.* However, there is no fixed reason that needs to be the case.  *Those with me on the trip were ...* can handle the case were *me* is first, if you want to say it.

Comment: When there's no grammatical reason to put one or the other first use what sounds better to you. "Her and me" sounds weird but "me and her" sounds natural. As long as it's the objective case of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I think the whole sentence is a bit clumsy with either.

I would suggest something along the lines of:

> I was surprised Paola had decided to come on the trip, as
>   it would be just the two of us.

Of course, I could be misreading the meaning of your original sentence - I'm assuming you are surprised because Paola has decided to attend a trip with just yourself?

Comment: Yes, but I think I find your sentence even more confusing. *As it would be?* Sounds like something that *is* and *would be* at the same time. Maybe I'm mistaken. The sentence just means, Paola decided to come with me to the trip, even though it was **just me and her**. The one I wrote it's just a shorter version.

Comment: At the time you were surprised, the trip was a future event - so you _were_ surprised, because of what _would_ result.. does that make sense?